# Sticky footer breaks in landscape orientation

Tags: html, css, landscape, sticky-footer

My sticky footer is not working in landscape orientation. I'm trying to create two divs, each of an equal height, that together will take up all the available height between my header and footer when the mobile device (of width 749px or less) is in portrait orientation. However, when the device is in landscape orientation, I want the divs to maintain a minimum height of 172 pixels each.

In addition, within each div, I want nested a vertically and horizontally centered, smaller div.

Everything looks fine in portrait orientation. In landscape orientation, the footer rests at the bottom of the viewport, rather than at the bottom of the second div.

".index-content" is the div I am using/attempting to use to keep the footer at the bottom of the page. The header has a fixed height of 192px - the footer has a fixed height of 32px (2em).

I've noticed that, in landscape orientation, the html and body elements only stretch to the bottom of the viewport. I've set the height of each to 100%, however, so I don't understand why that's happening. Is this a problem with my meta tag?

I'm sure the solution is somewhat obvious but I've been unable to suss it out. Any help would be appreciated!

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 749px) {
  /* -------Header and footer stuff start-----*/
  * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
  }
  html {
    height: 100%;
  }
  body {
    height: 100%;
  }
  .index-content {
    min-height: calc(100% - 2em);
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: calc(100% - 2em);
  }
  .footer {
    height: 2em;
    background-color: black;
  }
  header {
    height: 192px;
    background-color: black;
  }
  /*------Header and footer stuff end--------*/
  /*-------Services stuff---------*/
  .wrapper-content {
    max-width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    height: calc(100% - 192px);
  }
  .services-one {
    height: 50%;
    background-color: blue;
    min-height: 172px;
    max-width: 256px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
  .services-one-sub-one {
    height: 95%;
    width: 95%;
    background-color: red;
  }
  .services-two {
    height: 50%;
    background-color: green;
    min-height: 172px;
    max-width: 256px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
  .services-two-sub-one {
    height: 95%;
    width: 95%;
    background-color: yellow;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="index-content">
  <header>
  </header>
  <div class="wrapper-content">
    <div class="services-one">
      <div class="services-one-sub-one">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="services-two">
      <div class="services-two-sub-one"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<footer class="footer">
  <p>footer text</p>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace 100% height and 100vh and also some little tweeks as per below code:

If you want to show inside box with some particular height in landscape mode(where height is so much less), assign min-height to wrapper-content class.

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 749px) {
  /* -------Header and footer stuff start-----*/
  * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
  }
  .index-content {
    min-height: calc(100vh - 2em);
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
  .footer {
    height: 2em;
    background-color: black;
  }
  header {
    height: 8em;
    background-color: black;
  }
  /*------Header and footer stuff end--------*/
  /*-------Services stuff---------*/
  .wrapper-content {
    max-width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    height: calc(100vh - 10em);
  }
  .services-one {
    height: 50%;
    background-color: blue;
    max-width: 256px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
  .services-one-sub-one {
    height: 95%;
    width: 95%;
    background-color: red;
  }
  .services-two {
    height: 50%;
    background-color: green;
    max-width: 256px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
  .services-two-sub-one {
    height: 95%;
    width: 95%;
    background-color: yellow;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="index-content">
  <header>
  </header>
  <div class="wrapper-content">
    <div class="services-one">
      <div class="services-one-sub-one">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="services-two">
      <div class="services-two-sub-one"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<footer class="footer">
  <p>footer text</p>
</footer>
```

Comment: This worked, thanks! I have two questions dealing with why - 1) I was under the impression that if I wanted to use a percentage height on a child div (the "sub" divs in this case) I had to explicitly state the percentage height of every parent up the chain - hence 100% html and body height, and both the min-height and height declarations on index-content. This is false? 2) Why the min-height on the wrapper-content and not the "services-one" and "services-two" divs? Thanks if you have the time to answer. If this is poor etiquette just let me know.

Comment: If possible, try to thumb up my answer.

Comment: I did. I have too few points for it to be publicly recorded, but it said it was saved...